# Electron js, How to pass variable from main.js to html template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, ipc

I am a beginner to javascript & electron js. Im creating a todo list manager. Im trying to pass this list of titles retrieved from sqlite todos.db, and populate it in a selection menu. I am not sure how to pass the variable retrieved from database to html render page. When I actually click the corresponding button the list populates for one second and vanishes. Need some guidance.

Snippet of main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('todos.db');

ipcMain.on("deleteList", (event, data) => {
        db.all('SELECT title FROM lists', [], function (error, rows) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        return;
        }
        const listNames = rows.map(row => row.title);
        mainWindow.webContents.send("listNames", listNames);
        mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'delete-list.html'));
        console.log("main js working");
    
        });
    });
```

Snippet of index.js:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipcRenderer.on("listNames", (event, listNames) => {
  const listSelect = document.getElementById("list-select");
  console.log("index.js working")

  listNames.forEach(listName => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = listName;
    option.value = listName;
    listSelect.appendChild(option);
  });
});
```

delete-list.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Task Master</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <h2 id="heading">Task Master V1.0</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="operations">
      <select id="list-select">
        <option disabled selected>Select the list</option>
      </select>
      <button onclick="deleteList()" id="submit">Delete</button>
      <button id="home" onclick="window.location.href = 'index.html';">Back To Home</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this:

```
mainWindow.webContents.send("listNames", listNames);

mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'delete-list.html'));
```

You populate the list by

```
mainWindow.webContents.send("listNames", listNames);
```

and then reload the file effectively removing the list by

```
mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'delete-list.html'));
```

Try switching like this:

```
mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'delete-list.html'));

mainWindow.webContents.send("listNames", listNames);
```

Keep in mind that the send might trigger before your html page finish loading.

You could eg fetch listnames on page load in your delete-list.html

Hope this helps!